# Getting started with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I need to write a function that is the recursive version of summing up numbers 1 through n.  It needs to be recursive, which I have no idea how to do, although I did the iterative version quite easily.

All I know about recursion is that you call the function in the function.  Any help on where to get started is greatly appreciated.

Here is the iterative version I did.

```
def summ(n):
    result = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1,1):
        result = result + i
    return result
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785897/using-recursion-to-sum-numbers

Comment: When thinking about recursion, I've always found it helpful to formulate an English sentence for how my recursion works. In this case I might say something like "The `sum` from `1` to `n` can be described as: `n` plus the `sum` of `1` to `n-1`." While you still have to define base cases and such, I've always found a good sentence helps me visualize the execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As always with recursive functions, define a base case and a recursive case, then implement these in a function that checks whether it's reached the base case. There are various recursive algorithms for this problem, one of which is:

**Base case**. `n==1`. The sum is trivial.

**Recursive case**. If you have the sum of the numbers through `n`, how do you get the sum through `n+1`?

Comment: Depending on how you want your function to handle values less than 1, I'd say the base case should be `n <= 1`.

Comment: @MannyD: the OP wants to sum "numbers 1 through n". In practice, I'd just write `sum(xrange(n+1))`.

Comment: Yeah I'm always thinking error cases and if you call your function with 0 or less, you'd best be prepared to handle it otherwise you might have your function infinitely recur on itself. In normal cases, yes, that base case would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion happens when a function, in order to calculate its own result, calls itself with modified arguments and waits for that function call to return before continuing the calculation. That other function call might then call itself again with other modified arguments, and so recursion continue until it hits a case where the function does not need to call itself to calculate its result, and this case is called the **base case**. For summing numbers from 1 to N, the base case can obviously be for the number 1. Translating that to code, you would have something like :

```
def addup(n):
  if n == 1:
    return 1
  else:
    new_n = # the new N which needs to be passed to the recursion
    return n+addup(new_n)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer is in order,using the base case as m==1

```
def summ(m):
    if m==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return m+summ(m-1)
```